# What is the terminology for a product of a ring with a group (like the quaternions) or (more generally) with a monoid (like a polynomial ring)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, monoid, group-rings

I don't think there is much for me to elaborate beyond the title question: "What is the terminology for a product of a ring with a group (like the quaternions) or (more generally) with a monoid (like a polynomial ring)?"

I know the quaternions require a field, and fields are rings, so the example holds.  Also, it is popular example and was the first to come to mind.  Though, if you think I should put something else instead or in addition to, please let me know.

So, if you know of terminology for any of the four products of a field or (preferably) ring with a group or (preferably) monoid, please let know each one you know. (In case of confusion, the four products I'm referring to are field with group, field with monoid, ring with a group, and ring with monoid.)

If you can think of anything useful for me to elaborate, please let me know.

Edit: Right before I was about to submit this, I remembered some of the answer.  A product of a ring with a group is called a group ring, right?  Ring with a monoid is a monoid ring, right?  Is there terminology for the other two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think anyone calls the group ring $R[G]$ “the product of a group and a ring”, but evidentially that is what you are talking about.  Yes, the same construction using a monoid instead of a group Is called a “monoid ring $R[M]$.”

When the ring is a field, you could also call it “the group algebra $k[G]$” or “the monoid algebra $k[M]$, respectively.

There are also semigroup rings and semigroup algebras which do not take much imagination to define starting from this point.

> What is the terminology for a product of a ring with a group (like the quaternions)

One more comment to address this: the quaternions themselves are *not* a group ring over a nontrivial group.  The problem is that it is a simple ring, and $R[G]$ is not simple unless $|G|=1$ and $R$ is simple.

I *imagine* you thought $\mathbb R[Q]$ is related to $\mathbb H$, where $Q$ is the quaternion group. It is, but not directly: $\mathbb H$ is a quotient of $\mathbb R[Q]$ and not a group ring itself.

Comment: I would say "monoid/group ring" refers to the specific case where $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and all other cases (not just when $R$ is a field) are "monoid/group algebra".

Comment: @EricWofsey Assuming there are not serious typos in that comment, I would say that is definitely not how they are used in standard textbooks on Group rings/group algebras.  I have in mind Passmans book and Milies and Sehgal ‘s book.  Certainly nobody uses the word algebra with  $R[G]$ when $R$ is noncommutative.  Is that a convention used by a specific discipline, say, representation theory?  I also cannot really claim to know how monoid-ring literature does it. I assumed consistency but that is probably dangerous.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I was assuming $R$ was commutative.  I don't know of a specific place I've seen this convention; I guess I've just long assumed it was the obvious convention: the monoid ring is the ring freely generated by a monoid, and the monoid $R$-algebra is the $R$-algebra freely generated by a monoid.

Comment: @EricWofsey ive only seen “group algebra” paired with fields as coefficients but I suppose it is not crazy to let it run to commutative rings.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks! Is it not a product of a group and a ring?  And, if it is, is there anything wrong with wording it that way?

Comment: @EricWofsey (and at rschwieb) Thanks for trying to parse this out.  It is certainly helpful for me, as I'm sure it will be for others.

Comment: @user3146 Nobody says that, is all. It’s be better to say “a ring generated by a group”.  Following your convention, one would call a vector space a “product of a field with a set” which would be odd.

Comment: @rschwieb gotcha, thanks!

Comment: @rschwieb Well, on second thought, we wouldn't call a vector space a field generated by a set though, right?  Am I just reaching too far with the comparison?

Comment: @user3146 You just have it the wrong way around: it’s a thing (a vector space) generated by a set and a field.  The group ring is a thing (a ring) generated by a group and a ring.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, I must have been tired.  The ring generated by the group was the group ring, not the ring it is also generated by.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, I'm just now noticing (or seeing, if you edited) the part about the quaternion group ring and the Hamiltonian quaternions.  I forgot to address that.  Would I call R[Q] the (or a) quaternion group ring?  Also, I tried to edit a one letter typo, but the system made me do more than six not counting spaces, so I added a comma, changed a "don't" to a "do not" and a "can" to a "could", with only the comma change (maybe the "do not") being meaningful at all. The original change was "When then ring" to "When the ring".

Comment: @user3146 Yes, I spotted the reasons for the edit, it's fine.  You could call $\mathbb R[Q]$ "the real quaternion group ring" but I don't know if people do it. $\mathbb R[Q]$ just seems dandy to me.